# Book where years are counted as miles

Tags: story-identification, books

There is a science fiction book I picked up from a library 15 years ago that I would like to track down, as I recall enjoying it as well as finding it very unique.  I remember very little of it, but am fairly sure of the following: (hopefully I am not mixing up books, this was a while ago).

I believe it had a memorable opening line like "I was born 15 miles ago" or "I am 18 miles old."
This is because the main character lived in some sort of structure built on a rail, and the inhabitants were constantly laying new rail to move along in a straight line, and therefore instead of counting time in years, they counted in miles.

At one point the main character went on a journey (maybe to the end of the "world") where he  met a woman.

The ending half of the book was quite unique in that the main character who we'd been following actually fell largely out of the picture, and a new character turned into the protagonist and carried the story to its finish, which was a surprising twist.

That's really all I can recall, but it feels specific enough that I have hope someone will recognize this and let me know the title.

Comment: A whiff of Watts' *Rifters* works in that, but it does not sound like you are asking about space opera.

Comment: @Lexible No, the opening line is really the key, and this would have been an "old classic", probably had been on the library shelf for a long time.

Comment: This is probably Priest's *Inverted World*.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks! That's got to be it and reading the wikipedia page is making me even more excited to reread it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to be [*The Inverted World*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1706) (1974) by Christopher Priest.

The first part begins:

> I had reached the age of six hundred and fifty miles.  Beyond the door the guildsmen were assembling for the ceremony in which I would be admitted as a guild apprentice.